# render 1 Frame of Big Buck Bunny fails

Tags: cycles-render-engine, memory-management

Im trying to render a single frame of BigBuckBunny with blender 2.72b on linux.
I downloaded all the files needed (2d blender files + http://graphicall.org/bbb/index.php )

Now I want to render a single frame as a .PNG file - but whatever I try initiates a crash. I tried it at university with an incredible machine - lots of RAM, competent CPU, a GPU, etc. I also tried it at home on my pc and on a virtual machine.

At this point, I don't really know what I am doing wrong.

- render-format = .PNG
- use-extension = 1
- render-frame = 250

I always end up with the following crash message:

```
Fra:250 Mem:407.65M (430.03M, Peak 1156.72M) Sce: set Ve:615361 Fa:1079136 La:21
Saved: /home/user/blender/2d/test_0250.png Time: 00:39.88 (Saving: 00:00.21)

Error: Not freed memory blocks: 30
```

And Blender quits.

```
Ve:615361 Fa:1079136
```

Ve always same number - Fa changes

When I try it with the Cycles render engine, I don't get an error, but the PNG file produced is far inferior to the original.

Comment: Does it output a png? I don't see anything really wrong with that output..

Comment: Please use full words instead of texting acronyms and symbols.

Comment: when i use cycles it does a png - but it looks really wired and like i said its not even close to the original - if i dont use cycles it just crashes and doesnt output anything

Comment: I'd expect you'd need to use the blender version that was used to make those files. Try something pre-2.5 era. (Older versions can be downloaded from here: http://download.blender.org/release/ )